# Howto: Live Validation with jQuery and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i was wondering if there is a plugin/gem for live validatio with jquery.
I alreay knew some jquery plugins, but is there something out there which make use of ActiveRecord?

g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout http://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations. Tutorial available at http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations